# HTML anchor element bigger than parent div, clickable area smaller than intended

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to guarantee that the size of the anchor element should be fully clickable?

I'm doing maintenance in a website where the parent div of the  tag width is smaller than the area it should be clickable, so even if the  element is the correct size, half of it is not clickable.

Basically this is the code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>">
      <img class="logo-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" > 
      <img class="logo-icon-img" src="<?= base_url('site/images/logos/logo-icon.png') ?>" style="display: none">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I add a `style="display: inline-block"` inside the  tag, it fills the correct size (the image) of what should be clickable, but as the `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1">` is smaller than the image, the clickabe area is limited.

I would like to know if it's possible to force the clickable area without changing any CSS from the other classes/elements.

Even if I increase the `<div class="logo">` width, the a clickable area is still limited to the its parent size.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what you mean. You want the anchor to take up all the space of the parent?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet demo I created above, what you describe doesn't occur. Please revise the demo to show your problem.

Comment: Can you wrap ```<div class="logo"``` inside of anchor tag?

Comment: Also, you're clearly using Bootstrap here, which means that the column CSS is a factor. Please tag your Bootstrap version and add the library  to the demo via CDN.

Comment: This is the live website. 
https://mundoconectado.com.br/
As you can see in the menu logo, half of it is not clickable. Inspecting the <a> tag, it's big enough, but the clickable area is not.

Comment: @epascarello I want the anchor to be bigger than the parent. The area is already bigger, but the clickable area is not. Check the link above and you'll understand.

Comment: @isherwood I've added a comment with the live website, it's easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Nikkkshit the limiting div is the <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1">, not the logo div.

Comment: The problem is you have ANOTHER element that is covering up the logo. It has nothing to do with the anchor or the code you have shown. Right click and inspect the element on the unclickable portion. You get the div beside it.

Comment: You need to add z-index on the first column like `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1" style="z-index: 1">`

Comment: @epascarello gotcha. The div on the right is the one causing this issue then.

Comment: @Simp4Code thanks, that worked! If you submit an answer I can mark it as answered :)

Comment: Or fix the actual issue using correct layout so the content does not overlap.

Comment: Answers can't be provided without having all the necessary information in your question post. We don't debug other websites, and we don't address problems described only in comments. See [ask] and take the [tour] if you need a refresher.

Comment: @JulianodeMiranda its a quick fix not really an answer, glad it helped though. You should attempt to fix the layout, maybe with flex or grid or something — bootstrap do have just a .col class which resizes automatically based on the content as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `display: flex` in the **anchor element styling** and then the anchor element is taking the full width inside the div, I hope this is what you wanted.

Here is the working [demo](https://jsbin.com/wewupebida/edit?html,output)